# How to loop through all data frames in a list to pad the beginning and end with zeroes

Tags: r, loops

I made a list with 51 data frames, each df has two columns (x=year, y=count).  I am trying to pad every df with 33 zeroes at the beginning and end (as to lengthen the data frame by 66 years total).  I have tried to make a for loop without success.

This is what I have so far:

```
dflist=list(df1,df2,...df51)
```

`df1
Year Count
1953  1
1954  1
 .    .
 .    .
2018  1
zeroPad1=cbind(1920:1952,rep(0,33)) 
colnames(zeroPad1)=c("Year","Count") 
zeroPad2=cbind(2019:2051,rep(0,33)) colnames(zeroPad2)=c("Year","Count")`

```
for (i in 1:51) {
zeroPadUS=rbind(zeroPad1, mumpsUSList[i], zeroPad2)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `mumpsUSList[[i]]` with the double brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `data.table` package and `rbindlist` function to get what you want:

```
library(data.table)

new_list <- lapply(dflist, function(df){
  pad_dt <- data.table(Year = 2019:2051, Count = 0)
  ret <- rbindlist(l = list(pad_dt, df, pad_dt), use.names = T, fill = T)
  return(ret)
})
```

Basically, we're using `lapply` to loop through the list (a more 'R' way of doing things compared to `for` or `while` loops imo). For each entry in the list, we create a local list with `pad_dt` above and below the `data.frame` we want to pad, then use `rbindlist` to convert the list into a single `data.table` (also a `data.frame`).

Comment: That helped a bit but there was some error. Each df now has three columns: Year, Count, and X (X being the count for each year for that specific df). X is coming back as NA in the new_list.  Also, I still want to maintain two columns, but have the X equal 0 for years 1920-1952 and 2019-2051 if that makes sense

Comment: I tweaked the code you provided and it works.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Seeing this now. Yes, that can happen if `df3`, say, contains the same year as `pad_dt`. I assumed the years to pad data with are consistent for each data.frame in your list. You could order your data.frame (`df3` in this example) based on year and then create pad_dt based on the smallest and largest year value before padding it. Anyway, please upvote or accept if the answer works for you. Cheers!